# google apps script scan text as typed?

Tags: google-apps-script

Does anyone know if it's possible to have an apps script scan the document as the user types? Say, for example, to check spelling. Or, in my case, look for keywords typed and popup a dialogue as it spots them?

Comment: I think this post will be interesting for you, it's actually and at this time the only solution I know : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630221/write-a-code-that-let-you-know-how-many-word-in-your-word-document-at-google-dri/25633074#25633074

Comment: @Sergeinsas thanks. Not sure. The github link to cursorInspector is dead, now. So I am wondering if that was somehow polling the main document on some sort of regular update call? Is that even possible?

Comment: exactly, sorry that it doesn't work, here is another link on my drive, copy it to try it. https://docs.google.com/document/d/14fQybztLplJhnhPw9LgpNYrm2PJQgT9SW2SIIutz5qk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

To-date, the only trigger available on the document object is onOpen.  To do what you're asking for, there would need to be an onEdit trigger as well.  That exists on Spreadsheets, but not on Docs.  Hope that helps.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/document-trigger-builder